# How to interpret glmnet coefficients when computed on ln-transformed data

Tags: regression, machine-learning, lasso, elastic-net

So I'm analyzing data from a paper I found, which includes categorical variables like sex and disease severity as well as lipidomics data. I wanted to try using elastic-net regression to find parameters that were associated with patient death and with disease. I decided to use the R glmnet package and fit two models on the data; one for death/survival, and one for disease/control.

I did this:

```
set.seed(2023)

cv_10 <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10)

el.net <- train(
  is_dead ~ ., 
  data=ml.data, 
  method = "glmnet",
  trControl = cv_10
)

get_best_result = function(caret_fit) {
  best = which(rownames(caret_fit$results) == rownames(caret_fit$bestTune))
  best_result = caret_fit$results[best, ]
  rownames(best_result) = NULL
  best_result
}

get_best_result(el.net)

X = model.matrix(is_dead ~ ., ml.data)
y = ml.data$is_dead

fit_lasso_cv = cv.glmnet(X, y, alpha = 0.55, family="binomial") # I'm using the alpha that I got as a best result after cross-validation
sqrt(fit_lasso_cv$cvm[fit_lasso_cv$lambda == fit_lasso_cv$lambda.min]) # CV-RMSE minimum

coefs <- coef(fit_lasso_cv)
rownames(coef(fit_lasso_cv, s = 'lambda.min'))[coef(fit_lasso_cv, s = 'lambda.min')[,1]!= 0]
df_coefs <- summary(coefs)
df_coefs$i <- rownames(coefs)[summary(coefs)$i]
```

and then I did the same for the "group" variable, which states whether the sample comes from a healthy control or a patient.

Now, I log-transformed the lipidomics data so that the differences in the magnitude of the concentrations wouldn't affect the model. Is this okay? Should I have just worked on the raw data? Since concentrations are ratios, I assumed it made sense to log-transform (natural logarithm), but I didn't do that for variables like age.

Also, should I transform the coefficients back to interpret them?

This is the paper: https://doi.org/10.3390/ijms241411614